# Increase java heap space in Tomcat - Windows 7 Client

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, geoserver

I have Apache Tomcat installed on my Windows 7 Client machine, and am utilising geoserver.war as a deployment.

I keep on getting timed out/Java memory issues within Geoserver.
[(http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/]

There are lots of examples on how to increase space under Linux but not under a Windows Client.   I currently have 8GB of DDR5 memory and an Intel Core i5.

Any ideas on how I increase this on a Windows Client?

Comment: Increasing the heap space for Java is identical in Windows and Linux, you need to pass the `-Xmx` parameter. For Tomcat this is usually done through the `setenv` script - which would be called `setenv.bat` in Windows and `setenv.sh` on Linux

Comment: Run with a profiler first to identify any memory leaks.  Jvisualvm or Netbeans are good starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the `JVM` heap space by adding the following parameters, also it should work on Windows and Linux:

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
```

In order to add them under tomcat:

- Navigate and open `tomcat7w.exe` inside `[TOMCAT_HOME]/bin`
- Go to `Java tap`, then add them under `Java Options`

Comment: Would this be run under the DOS Command Line?  What is exact command I have to use (with parameter).

Comment: No worries about DOS - I have now followed your instructions and it has worked correctly.